# Getmethod Invoke fails with exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to call get_ConnectionString method from my static function. But i am getting exception .

My code is as below

```
PropertyInfo[] myPropertyInfo;

var ss = Type.GetType("System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection,System.data, version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089", false, true);
myPropertyInfo = ss.GetProperties();
for (int i = 0; i < myPropertyInfo.Length; i++)
{
    System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.AppendText("C:\\Temp\\out.txt");
    if(myPropertyInfo[i].GetMethod.ToString().Contains("get_ConnectionString") == true)
    {
         var obj1 = myPropertyInfo[i].GetMethod.Invoke(null,null);
         sw.WriteLine(obj1);
    }
    sw.Close();
}
```

The above code should write connection string in out.txt file . But I am getting the exception

> *System.Reflection.TargetException: Object does not match target type. at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.CheckConsistency(Object
>   target)*

How can I get this done? What I am making wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the object instance to call that method on: `Invoke(sqlConnection, null)`. The error message is misleading.

Comment: Thanks .. But is that possible to have run time accesss to the get_ConnectionString from a static function ? So that it should return the string that is just assigned from some X function.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no static connection string. It just does not exist. Specify an instance.

Comment: I am try to inject this code thru a static function into Connection.Open() so that i will get the connection string. Is there any other possible way to know the connection string thru injecting out code at runtime ?

Comment: What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: I need to profile the db queries in a .Net application and their execution time from my profiler ( developed in C++ using ILRewriting).

Comment: Well, replacing .NET code is not possible using Reflection APIs so I'd say this is out of scope for this question.